# Trouble with training simple policy agent. Error: Cannot find a connection between any variable and the result of the loss function y=f(x)

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to create a policy network agent for playing Tic Tac Toe using tensorflow.js and node.

When I run my training step at the end of the game I get the following

`Error: Cannot find a connection between any variable and the result of the loss function y=f(x). Please make sure the operations that use variables are inside the function f passed to minimize().`

```
class NNModel {
  constructor(learning_rate = 0.01){
    this.learning_rate = learning_rate
    this.model = this.createModel()
  }

  train(actions, rewards, boards) {

    const optimizer = tf.train.rmsprop(this.learning_rate, 0.99)

    optimizer.minimize(() => {
      const oneHotLabels = tf.oneHot(actions, BOARD_SIZE).dataSync()
      const logits = this.model.predict(tf.tensor(boards)).dataSync()
      const crossEntropies = tf.losses.softmaxCrossEntropy(oneHotLabels, logits).asScalar()
      const loss = tf.tensor(rewards).mul(crossEntropies)
      return loss
    })
  }

  createModel() {
    const model = tf.sequential()

    model.add(
      tf.layers.dense({
        units: BOARD_SIZE * 3 * 9,
        activation: 'relu',
        inputShape: [BOARD_SIZE * 3]
      })
    )

    model.add(
      tf.layers.dense({
        units: BOARD_SIZE,
      })  
    )

    return model
  }
}
```

In my SimplePolicyAgent as part of every move step I save the board state to a log, use the model to pick the move and also save that to a log.

At the end of the game I get the result and create a list the same length as the move log with rewards based on the result of the game.

Then I call the train function with the actions, rewards and boards.

I expect this step to update the model weights such that the model will be more likely to pick winning moves for a given board state.

I'm attempting to emulate the following python implementation

```py
#loss
cross_entropies tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(one_hot_labels=tf.one_hot(actions, 7), logits=Ylogits)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(rewards * cross_entropies)

#training op
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, decay=0.99)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Thanks for reading my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computing the gradient of the loss using Tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728772/computing-the-gradient-of-the-loss-using-tensorflow-js)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Are you suggesting that the function passed into minimize() should return tf.variableGrads(f) in some way? I'll have a dig at that when I get home. Not entirely sure if this is the solution but it is at least an avenue for investigation. Thanks

Comment: The function passed to minimize does not have to return `tf.variableGrads`. Both methods expects trainable variables.
Optimizer.minimize try to minimize an error as regard the variables. So the scalar returned by the function passed to optimizer.minimize should have trainable variables `tf.Variable` to indicate training, hence the error

Comment: `minimize (f, returnCost?, varList?)` As I understand from the docs the varList is all trainable variables if not supplied explicitly. I did try passing this.model.weights however and got the error `Error: The varList passed in variableGrads(f, varList) must be an array of variables` I was going to try and extract the variables from the list of LayerVariables supplied by model.weights but that seemed too much of a stab in the dark to actually work. Even if it did mean my code ran I wouldn't be confident it is doing the right thing.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly specify the trainable variables as there are optional. Could you share the code of the method `predict` as maybe you're using it inside `tf.tidy` ?

Comment: `predict` in the function passed minimize is just vanilla `tf.Sequential.predict` However I do wrap the calls to predict inside the agent in a `tf.tidy`. I'll see if I can create a codepen with some example data

Comment: I think that `tf.tidy` is preventing the `tf.variable` of the weights of the layers to be trainable for the `minimize` method.

Comment: I removed the `tf. tidy` from the `Agent` code and get the same error. I'm working on https://codepen.io/PaulBunkerWhich/pen/mgyqmB?editors=0010 in an attempt to provide a reduced test case WIP at the moment while I try and get it to give the same error that I see in node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191041/discussion-between-paul-bunker-and-edkeveked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  train(actions, rewards, boards) {
    const optimizer = tf.train.rmsprop(this.learning_rate, 0.99)
    return optimizer.minimize(() => {
      const oneHotLabels = tf.oneHot(actions, BOARD_SIZE)
      const logits = this.model.predict(tf.tensor(boards))
      const crossEntropies = tf.losses.softmaxCrossEntropy(oneHotLabels, logits)
      const loss = tf.sum(tf.tensor(rewards).mul(crossEntropies)).asScalar()
      return loss
    })
  }
```

This code now runs without the error, I was erroneously adding `.dataSync()` to the `oneHotLabels` and `logits` which was hiding the variables from the minimize function.